# Parametrization in Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, azure, hive, databricks

I tried parametrization in Databricks notebook in SQL. It works fine when I am using the parameters in a condition as a value but gives error when I am trying to append/concatenate it with a table/column name. PFB screenshot for the reference :-

Works fine when tried when the variable passed as a value or when concatenate with a static value.

```
set week_yr = cast(WEEKOFYEAR(current_date()) as string);
set anyvar = 2023;
select ${hiveconf:week_yr} as week_of_${hiveconf:anyvar};
```

Throws an error when the variable is passed while appending with a column name .

```
set week_yr = cast(WEEKOFYEAR(current_date()) as string);
set anyvar = 2023;
select ${hiveconf:week_yr} as week_of_${hiveconf:week_yr};

Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '('(line 1, pos 65)
```

Does anyone have an idea on this ?

Comment: Could you please provide your code instead of screenshot? It will be helpful to the community to provide the solution

Comment: Are you using the Databricks Unity Catalog?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula how do we check that ?

Comment: @HemantSingh
%sql
set week_yr = cast(WEEKOFYEAR(current_date()) as string);
set week_yr_alias = concat('week_of_', ${hiveconf:week_yr});
select ${hiveconf:week_yr} as `${hiveconf:week_yr_alias}`;

Can you try this once

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula This is also not working.
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '('(line 1, pos 59)

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula I need to concatenate this with a tablename while creating it so this won't work there even if it would've worked here

Answer (score 0):

It works when you provide an exact value, but it doesn't when you give an expression because the expression doesn't evaluate when setting the value. It only evaluates when you perform a select.

```sql
set week_yr =  cast(WEEKOFYEAR(current_date()) as string);
```

[image]

It sets the literal value you provide.

And if you try to concatenate this for aliasing a column, it takes the exact value.

```sql
select ${hiveconf:week_yr} as  `week_of_${hiveconf:week_yr}`;
```

[image]

So, it doesn't evaluate the expression unless you perform a `select`. However, using `select`, you can't create a table name with dynamic values. Therefore, my idea is to use identifiers.

```sql
DECLARE week_year =  cast(WEEKOFYEAR(current_date()) as string);
CREATE  TABLE  IDENTIFIER('week_of_'  || week_year)(c1 INT);
```

and

```sql
describe IDENTIFIER('week_of_'  || week_year);
```

Output:

[image]