# Databricks change data feed

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, ansi-sql

According to documentation change data feed on Databricks
support both  batch queries and streaming queries.

I was wondering if there is anyway to pass the parameters inside the [batch queries](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html#read-changes-in-batch-queries).

More specifically, lets say I want to read the change feed starting from version 3. Actuall query will look like this =>

`SELECT * FROM table_changes('tableName', 3)`

But I want to pass this `3` parameter using some kind of variable which will be based on the table, so I query `table`, retrive the `max(version)` and that value should be 3.

My pseudo code looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM table_changes("catalog.bronze.bronze_table", (SELECT MAX(version) FROM catalog.silver.silver_table))`

How can I pass this  `3` parameters inside the query using only the Databricks SQL and no spark at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the stack solution below, which shows how to use `IDENTIFIER` for column names, as it supports various **DDL** statements like **CREATE**, **ALTER**, etc.

[azure - Parametrization in Databricks SQL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905259/parametrization-in-databricks-sql/77926984#77926984)

To get the `max(version)`, you need to refer to the **describe history** statement as mentioned in this solution and use it to filter `table_changes()` results.

For more information, you can refer to this documentation.

[IDENTIFIER clause](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-names-identifier-clause.html#identifier-clause)

This applies to **Databricks SQL** and **Databricks Runtime 13.2 and above**.